# woocommerce_form_field() doesn't render field where I specify

Tags: woocommerce, custom-fields

I need to create a brand new section to my checkout page and collect some important information from the user, then add this info the the standard email that gets sent out to our order fulfillment team.

Here is what I'm attempting to do:

First, I create a hook of my own within the checkout form page like so:

```
<div class="col2-set group">
  <div class="col col-1">
    <?php do_action('ni_card_form') ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then within the template hooks page for the checkout page I drop a function into this hook which will render a template I created to the page:

```
add_action( 'ni_card_form', 'render_card_form' );
```

Then the function called by the hook.

```
function render_card_form() {
   echo '
   <div class="group postpaid-card">
     <h3>PostPaid Recurring Billing</h3>
     <div class="my-input-field">
       <small class="card-type"></small>
       ' .
        woocommerce_form_field( 'c_card', array(
          'type'  => 'text',
          'class' => array('c_card', 'input-text'),
          'label' => __('Card Number:'),
          'placeholder' => "XA-12-3456-7817",
          'required' => true
        ))
        . '
       <p class="c-error"></p>
     </div>
     <div class="my-input-field">
       <div class="col2-set group">
         <div class="col c-half c-first">
           ' .
            woocommerce_form_field( 'c_date', array(
              'type'  => 'text',
              'class' => array('c_date', 'input-text'),
              'label' => __('Exp. Date:'),
              'placeholder' => "MM/YY",
              'required' => true
            ))
           . '
         </div>
     </div>
   </div>';

}
```

If I replace the wooCommerce functions with normal HTML input fields, they will render in the right place. However, because it's using those wooCommerce functions to create those fields, it doesn't work. Instead it adds those fields to a different section of the page.

Why is this happening?

After looking at tutorials like this [one](http://www.portmanteaudesigns.com/blog/2015/02/04/woocommerce-custom-checkout-fields-email-backend/) It appears that it is possible to render those inputs within the html he's echo'ing out. Sure, he's using a hook to place the template somewhere (after notes) but it's still rendering the template as whole, not rendering the inputs elsewhere.

Why might this be happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is in the template function. I cannot add the functions to the string. I have to end each echo, call the woocommercie field function, and then start a new echo in order to build the template properly.

For example:

```
echo '<div id="my_custom_checkout_field"><h2>' . __('My Field') . '</h2>';

woocommerce_form_field( 'my_field_name', array(
    'type'          => 'text',
    'class'         => array('my-field-class form-row-wide'),
    'label'         => __('Fill in this field'),
    'placeholder'   => __('Enter something'),
    ), $checkout->get_value( 'my_field_name' ));

echo '</div>';
```

The structure here literally is:

```
echo '<some html code>';

woocomm function;

echo '</some html code>';
```

Now it works.